# MySQL: How To Check If User (Self) Has Permission To Create Temporary Tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql

What query would I have to use to check if the querying user has permissions to create temporary tables in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if there is an elegant way of doing this with a query, but a "hackish" type of way to do it would be to use a [mysql_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and see if you get a result for that table or an error.

```
function checkCreateTempPermission($table) {
     $res = mysql_query("CREATE `$table` "); // modify this to be your temporary table code.
     if ($res === false) {
         if (strstr(mysql_error(), "command denied to user")) {
              return false;
         }else {
              // some other error happened not sure how you want to handle it so left blank.
         }
     }else {
         return true;
     }
}
```

**I have not tested this at all**, more or less a **theory** of how it could be done. Alternatively, you can write a script that runs this SQL:

```
Show grants for myuser;
```

And then loop through that testing if they have access for that table. This would take a bit more work, but at least would not error out. Hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: I guess I'll run with Show Grants.